# Getting out of bound Error in python script while finding NDVI index from tiff image

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on getting NDVI index from an image into numeric so that i can print the NDVI numeric value.

For that purpose i was googling around and found one python code. i am using Ubuntu and i have pyhton 2 and 3 installed .

And i am very new to python.

```
# Import the Python 4 print function
from __future__ import print_function

# Import the "gdal" and "gdal_array" submodules from within the "osgeo" module
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array

# Import the NumPy module
import numpy as np

# Open a GDAL dataset
dataset = gdal.Open('/home/path to directory/A0_200_T.TIF', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

# Allocate our array using the first band's datatype
image_datatype = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).DataType

image = np.zeros((dataset.RasterYSize, dataset.RasterXSize, dataset.RasterCount),
                 dtype=gdal_array.GDALTypeCodeToNumericTypeCode(image_datatype))

# Loop over all bands in dataset
for b in xrange(dataset.RasterCount):
    # Remember, GDAL index is on 1, but Python is on 0 -- so we add 1 for our GDAL calls
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(b + 1)

    # Read in the band's data into the third dimension of our array
    image[:, :, b] = band.ReadAsArray()


print('Red band mean: {r}'.format(r=image[:, :, 2].mean()))
print('NIR band mean: {nir}'.format(nir=image[:, :, 3].mean()))
b_red = 2
b_nir = 3

ndvi = (image[:, :, b_nir] - image[:, :, b_red]) / \
        (image[:, :, b_nir] + image[:, :, b_red]).astype(np.float64)

print('NDVI matrix: ')
print(ndvi)

print('\nMax NDVI: {m}'.format(m=ndvi.max()))
print('Mean NDVI: {m}'.format(m=ndvi.mean()))
print('Median NDVI: {m}'.format(m=np.median(ndvi)))
print('Min NDVI: {m}'.format(m=ndvi.min()))
```

now when i run this script using "python name.py" it results me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ndvi.py", line 29, in <module>
    print('Red band mean: {r}'.format(r=image[:, :, 5].mean()))
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 1
```

It seems like array is storing out of bound data but i dont know how to fix this.(!??)

I also don't know weather it gives that NDVI index or not but i am hoping so.(please suggest me if is there another way to do so.)

Any help on this would be great appreciable.

Please let me know if you require more information.

Thank you in advance.
R.